# Converting text file to certain format c#

Tags: c#, parsing, file-io

I have a text file containing numbers and each number is separated by a tab. There are also several lines of these numbers. I wanted to read the file and store the file into an array but I am not sure how to do so.

**Sample file content**

```
   137  12.36922    .28200   4312170     .0550  108.4431   14.9959
   127  12.23045    .28200  10400044  140.9635   22.9278   19.8656
   514  12.91381    .42300  12550428     .1157   61.7263  123.4808
   209  12.26951    .28200  10432158     .0361    8.4094   69.3899
   271  12.68842    .35250     91375     .0663    3.6094   25.2950
   548  12.99388    .49350   2131433     .1386     .6384   78.6621
   314  12.54900    .35250  12469075     .1451   44.1327  115.9872
  1466  13.40586    .63450     27236  140.6160   53.3465   65.4476
    55  11.97313    .21150    100246     .0911   63.5528   60.7556
    27  11.66276    .21150  12353651  140.9790   42.3193  110.4559
    44  11.81954    .21150  10420688     .0447   38.5853    3.6592
```

Comment: Post sample of file. Parsing text files can be complicated if file contains data besides the numbers.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzdAMi1SfrRGZEJMNFRhSENBYWM/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to use `Linq`:

```
var text = File.ReadAllText(@"Your file path goes here");
var result = text.Split(" \r\n".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)?.Select(num => double.Parse(num)).ToArray()
```

If you want sorted data then you can use `OrderBy` or `OrderByDescending` extension methods:

```
var result = text.Split(" \r\n".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)?.Select(num => double.Parse(num)).OrderBy(d => d).ToArray()
```

Comment: Thank You! This worked perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the numbers are floats (you can parse to any type you like, this is just an example) then you could do soemthing like this:

```
string myFileString = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Temp\MyFile.txt");

string[] myStringArray = myFileString.Split('\t');

List<float> myNumberList = new List<float>();

foreach (string s in myStringArray)
{
    myNumberList.Add(float.Parse(s.Trim()));
}
```

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzdAMi1SfrRGZEJMNFRhSENBYWM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: This is the file I needed to be sorted. Would that method still work?

Comment: You have different data types in there (some integers and some floating points).  You would either need to store it in a more complex object, like a datatable or make your own class.  If you store the items into a array of a single type it will just be a long running list of numbers and you will have to choose the type (e.g. cast all to floating point types).  What is the end goal for the data?

Comment: The goal was to sort all this data using a sorting algorithm which is why I wanted to put it into an array first the send it to the sorting method.

Comment: So, what you have here is columns and lines.  Putting everything into a simple array would just give you a list of numbers (e.g. float myArray[] { 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5 }) but, this doesn't separate out the lines.  So you'll either need an array of arrays (multidimensional array) or a List of custom objects, or a data table.  What will your sorting method look like so that the best option can be recommended.